# Encrypt password with AES in PHP and decrypt it in Go

Tags: php, go, encryption, aes

In the frontend I'm using PHP (Symfony). In a PHP form the password is stored in the database, there I want to encrypt it. That same password is used in the backend for an API that in programmed in Go, there I need to decrypt it.

I like to use AES encryption, but if something better is proposed than that is also fine.

In backend I'm using the following GO function to decrypt it:

```
func DecryptAES(key []byte, ct string) string {
    ciphertext, _ := hex.DecodeString(ct)

    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)

    pt := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
    c.Decrypt(pt, ciphertext)

    s := string(pt[:])
    return s
}
```

I use for example the following input:

```
// cipher key
key := "1234567890123456"

// password
pt := "-This is secret-" // needs to be 16 chars
```

To decrypt with the key above I need to following Ciphertext: 55c6ca0c634fb5cc7d7a287d30285f09

How can I generate this Ciphertext with PHP?

I did try the following, but the outcome if different:

```
   $ct = openssl_encrypt('-This is secret-', 'AES-128-ECB', "1234567890123456");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "__In the frontend I'm using PHP (Symfony)__" ? PHP is a backend language.

Comment: Yes indeed, the application is in PHP. The API's in Golang

Comment: In the PHP code, default padding and default base64 decoding must be disabled. For this in `openssl_decrypt()` as 4th parameter `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING | OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` has to be passed. The hex encoding must be done explicitly with `bin2hex()`. Note that ECB is an insecure mode of operation.